# How to I make a drop down beside a search box that searches the specific field selected in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

Okay so im new to this site but this is what I have:

## Report.rb

```
def self.search(search)  
    if search  
      where('JOBLETTER_CD_NUMBER LIKE ? AND DATE LIKE? AND CUST LIKE ?', "%#{search}%") 
    else  
      scoped  
    end  
  end  
end
```

## index.html.erb

```
select_tag "search", options_for_select([ "Job Letter and CD #", "Date", "Cust", "Job", "Date shipped", "Date billed", "Billed by" ], params[:search]) 

form_tag reports_path, :method => 'get' do

text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class=> "form-search", :align => "right"

<%= submit_tag "Search", :JOBLETTER_CD_NUMBER => nil, :class => "btn btn-success", :align => "right"
```

## reports controller

```
def index
    @report = Report.paginate(:per_page => 1, :page => params[:page])
    @report = Report.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 1, :page => params[:page])  
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @views }

    end
  end
```

The only field it will search is the Job Letter and CD # field I need it to allow me to search whatever is selected in the drop down box. Btw I am using bootstrap fro js and css functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has 3 placeholders `?` but passed only one argument `"#{search}"` - if you run it like that, what you really should be getting is an exceptions stating

```
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables (1 for 3) ...
```

Also, your `select_tag` is outside the form, so it won't be passed to the controller at all. If you move it into the form, you'd have to rename (e.g. to `column`) it since the name `search` is already used by the text field. Then you could pass both the `column` and the `search` parameters to your search function to construct the query.

**HOWEVER**, this is not safe, since nothing prevents a user to pass in any other column by manipulating the post request, and since you can't use placeholders for column names, there's a danger of SQL injection as well.

There are many solutions out there to construct searches, no need to reinvent the wheel. Take a look at the [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/) gem. Here's a recent [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack) on how to use it.